# The error occurred during the CMake configuration for fairseq2n,Could NOT find Torch

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, pytorch, fairseq

I used **brew** to install relevant components, and used **conda** to create a virtual environment named **seamless_m4t**, in which I installed relevant python packages.

```bash
brew install ninja
brew install libsndfile
brew install libiconv

conda create -n seamless_m4t python=3.9
conda activate seamless_m4t

conda install -c conda-forge pre_commit
conda install -c conda-forge datasets
conda install -c pytorch torchaudio 
conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile
conda install -c conda-forge librosa
```

After that, I installed a Python package named **fairseq2** from source in the virtual environment, with the following steps:

```bash
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq2.git
export CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)
pip3 install torch -r fairseq2/fairseq2n/python/requirements-build.txt
cd fairseq2/fairseq2n
cmake -GNinja -B build
```

The *error* occurred during the CMake configuration for **fairseq2n**,Could NOT find Torch.

```bash
CMake Error at /Users/chong/miniconda3/envs/seamless_m4t/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Torch (missing: TORCH_LIBRARY TORCH_CPU_LIBRARY C10_LIBRARY
  TORCH_INCLUDE_DIR TORCH_API_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version
  "1.12")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/chong/miniconda3/envs/seamless_m4t/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindTorch.cmake:114 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:167 (find_package)
```

In a constructed Conda environment, when executing `pip3 list`,**torch** is already installed with version 2.0.1. Why is it unable to locate the Torch path?

My system is macOS Ventura 13.4.1

This is the issue I created on GitHub: https://github.com/chipcode-nl/mac-fairseq2/issues/1#issue-1884649037